# Make sure all virtual methods are overridden

Tags: c#, oop, virtual-functions

I have a base class where I need to make sure that all virtual methods are overwritten in class specializations. I cannot use an abstract class/methods since I need to execute some code in the base methods as well.

How do I do this?

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public virtual void DoStuff()
  {
    // do something
  }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  public override void DoStuff()
  {
     // do derived work
     base.DoStuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if you could (I don't believe you can), you wouldn't be able to force implementers to *call* your base methods when they've overridden them - was that meant to be a requirement too?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well, I have a bunch of test code that I need to test on some repositories. So I need to make sure that if I add tests to the "base test class" then all tests of the repositories test the new tests I have added. Basically I am trying to overcome the limitation of nunit's TestCaseAttribute that only supports primitive types. There are a number of rather simple solutions to this -but they all destroy the nunit test overview and makes it hard for me to figure out which tests fail on which classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use hooks, better known as the [template method pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html):

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
  public void Start()
  {
    // do something
    OnStart();
    // do something else
  }
  protected abstract void OnStart();
}
```

This employs my all-time favorite [Hollywood principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle), the basis of many frameworks: don't call us, we'll call you!

Comment: but that would mean simply moving the requirement to execute the Start()-method instead, right?

Comment: Oh wait - what your construct does is make the base class call the derived class. The requirement is the other way around - I want the derived class to call the base class.

Comment: @JesperLundStocholm Yes, this makes sure the derived implementation is called, because the abstract class calls it itself. You cannot force all derived classes to call the base class - I'm afraid you won't be able to enforce this rule. Documentation and team discipline is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

If you implement an abstract class like this it will do what you need.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{

  protected abstract void doAbstractStuff();

  public void DoStuff()
  {
    //base class code lives here
    doAbstractStuff();
    //or here?
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to put some code in the base class method doAbstractStuff()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a simple way to do this, but you could do this instead:

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public abstract void DoStuff();

  protected void DoStuffInternal()
  {
    // do something
  }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  public override void DoStuff()
  {
     // do derived work
     DoStuffInternal();
  }
}
```

Comment: This does mean you have to remember to call the internal method on every DerivedClass?

Comment: @Paddy I think this adds an artificial step to using the base class that makes derived usage rather non-intuitive.

Comment: Should have added a comment.  dcastro's answer is much better than this - he got my vote :)